# adding new syntax formatting to existing filetype

Tags: linux, vim, vi

So I have some custom vi coloring in a syntax file.

This works perfectly (giving a blue background to lines 20-30)

```
syntax region mytest start="\%20l" end="\%30l"

hi mytest ctermbg=Blue
```

This does not work at all (attempting to give a blue background to a range that starts with x and ends with y):

```
syntax region mytest2 start="x" end="y" fold transparent

hi mytest2 ctermbg=Blue
```

I'm trying to figure out how to give formatting between a start/end point.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the function of "transparent".  Removing transparent fixes the issue.